# exception while signaling: Must be a LuaSourceContainer

Tags: exception, lua, roblox

So I was just making game on Roblox and met strange exception:

```
exception while signaling: Must be a LuaSourceContainer - Studio
```

I think it comes from my own custom humanoid UI, but I am not sure.
Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out what I am doing wrong. I used

```
Humanoid.HealthChanged.Connect:(function()
--Changing UI
end)
```

When I needed to do something like this:

```
Humanoid:GetAttributeChangedSignal("Health"):Connect(function() 
--Function body
end)
```

But unfortunately, only `Players` have attribute `Health`. So, I used `repeat` loop `until` my humanoid health reaches (`<=`) 0. Very important to mention that if you use `Humanoid.Died` signal, you will instantly leave loop. I redid code and now it looks like this:

```
repeat
--Function body
wait(0.01) --NOTE: If you won't use wait(), you will freeze studio and get error.
until Humanoid.Health <= 0
```

Hopefully, this was helpful to anyone.

Comment: Why did it throw exception? Well, Roblox just loaded variable ```Humanoid``` before even humanoid spawned.

Answer (score 0):

`Humanoid` is being made into a variable before it exists.

**The Solution**: On **Line 1** make the script use `WaitForChild` on The `NPC` Model to prevent `NPC.Humanoid.HealthChanged:Connect()` from attempting to access the `HealthChanged` property of an object that is `nil` because it does not exist yet.

Use `NPC:WaitForChild("Humanoid")` instead of `NPC.Humanoid`.